# JDBC Connection times out in deployed web app with hosting service

Tags: sql-server, spring-mvc, tomcat, jdbc, hosting

I am using JDBC to create a connection to an MS SQL Server Database.  The same code and connection string works fine on a number of platforms and in particular in my spring MVC Web Application.

After deploying the web application to a remote tomcat hosting service, everything appears to work fine in the code except that the database connection times out.

```
"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to     the host <IP Address>, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."
```

The hosting company says I must provide the exact steps to recreate the problem which may not be ideal.  The only thing I can think of is to write another cut down application that connects to a different db with different credentials and test that in dev and deploy and then email them the war so they can deploy it and test it in their own environment.

Does anyone know of reasons why this might happen with a hosting service, like blocking the database response for some reason?  Or is this very unlikely and should I assume that I am doing something wrong and persevere in understanding what might be different between my dev app and deployed app that could cause this timeout.  Not that I can think of anything.

I don't want to take all that time if there is a common reason why this might happen that someone could point me to.

Thank you.

Comment: The first thing I see is the word 'remote'. Are the other platforms 'remote' from the SQL Server that are working? Or is this the first time the app has moved to a remote host?

Comment: The sql server is on a sql server hosting service.  The web app when deployed is on a different hosting service, differentr company.  The dev environment is my own local machine running sometimes pivotal tc server dev edition and sometimes regular tomcat deployed as a war (same tc version as the tomcat hosting).  Also connect from an Android App to sql server (hosting service) using JDBC same code same connection string (different jvm of course).  First time I have deployed the war to a remote host.  Hope that explains it.

Comment: Just to say thank you for looking at this any one.  I appreciate it.  The hosting company assured me there was absolutely no reason at their end that I could not connect to my SQL server db.  They have since contacted me to say they have opened up port 1433.  A very quick test suggests this has solved the problem, but I will test longer and more carefully tomorrow.  Thank you.

Comment: Very good. That was my next suggestion for the SQL port to open up. Sometimes the obvious is often overlooked.